# Time Difference of Consecutive Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, difference

I want to calculate time difference with consecutive rows where the 0 is machine start time and 1 is machine end time. Following are my code and screenshots link, this is incorrect code. You can regenerate this code.

Wrong output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbjPrRUswI5NoByNnWM8mFRlJBwPbnv5/view?usp=sharing

```
WITH TimeDuration (PumpID, PumpNo, Value, logdate, logtime,PlantType) 
AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        PumpID, PumpNo, Value, CONVERT(date, vPumpRunStatus.Date), 
        MAX(vPumpRunStatus.time), PlantType
    FROM 
        vPumpRunStatus
    INNER JOIN
        DIR ON vPumpRunStatus.PumpID = DIR.ID
    GROUP BY
        PumpID, PumpNo, Value, vPumpRunStatus.Date, 
        DATEPART(Minute, vPumpRunStatus.time), PlantType
) 
SELECT
    t1.PumpID, t1.PumpNo, t1.logdate, t2.Value, 
    t1.logtime AS StartTime, (t2.logtime) AS EndTime,
    CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(M, t1.logtime, (t2.logtime)) / 3600) + ':' +
        CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(M, t1.logtime, (t2.logtime)) % 3600 / 60) + ':' +
        CONVERT(varchar(5), (DATEDIFF(M, t1.logtime, (t2.logtime)) % 60)) AS TimeDifference
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM TimeDuration  
     WHERE Value = 0  
       AND PumpID = 91 
       AND PlantType = 3 ) t1
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT * 
      FROM TimeDuration 
      WHERE value = 1 
        AND PumpID = 91 
        AND PlantType = 3) t2 ON t2.PumpID = t1.PumpID
```

The desired output 'screenshot2' is also attached.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ZbZIT3RM_gY3RRP2lzFwfT-d42FJXgQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good solution for you is try to use the LAG SQL Funcion:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/

Using LAG, you find the value for the previous record.
After that, using CTE, you can have in the same row the older and newer record and calculate the time difference.

If i understood correctly your question, this can be the solution for you